# Использование ссылки на участок сложного вложенного словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется словарь с многомерной вложенностью

```
a = {"abc": {1: [1,2,3]}}
print(a["abc"][1])  # [1,2,3]
```

Представим, что  он не настолько простой, как показно. Представим, что имеет несколько сотен тысяч строк на каждом уровне вложенности. Не маленький словарь, в общем.

Далее стоит задача обновить некоторые части этого словаря в цикле

```
for i in range(1, 2):
    a["abc"][i] = 777
print(a["abc"][1])  # 777
```

Выходит, что на каждой интерации цикла (если бы их было много и словарь был не из примера, а реальный огромный) мы вновь и вновь ищем `a["abc"]` (понятно, может быть более глубокая вложенность) и присваиваем какое-то значение. Теоретически, можно создать в отдельной переменной ссылку на этот участок словаря и использовать уже её

```
link = a["abc"]
for i in range(1, 2):
    link[i] = 777
    print(a["abc"][1])  # 777
```

Даст ли это хоть что-то в плане производительности? Или же смысла в этом нет? Создаётся ссылка на участок в памяти, и мы эту ссылку используем.

Забавно выходит, если ссылку сделать на последний элемент вложенности и попробовать обновить его значение - ничего не происходит. Почему? Как можно всё таки обновить данные?

```
a = {"abc": {1: [1,2,3]}}
print(a["abc"][1])  # [1,2,3]


link = a["abc"][1]
print(len(link))  # 3

link = 7
print(a["abc"][1])  # [1,2,3] а не ожидаемое 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в словаре поиск O(1), ссылки ты можешь делать только для  удобства.

в последнем примере ты перезаписываешь переменную link, а не меняешь значение.

```
a = {"abc": {1: [1,2,3]}}
print(a["abc"][1])  # [1,2,3]


link = a["abc"][1]
print(len(link))  # 3

link.clear()
link.append(7)
print(a["abc"][1])  # [7]
```

Comment: а можно ли по ссылке не добавить в новый список `link.append(7)`, а вообще обойтись без списка, т.е. записать просто `7`?

Comment: Тогда link = a["abc"]; link[1] = 7. И все выше написанное справедливо только для изменяемых типов данных. dict, list, set